# What are the most known ML-models that use complex numbers? (if there are any)

Tags: machine-learning-model, model-selection

Basically just the header.

The question is out of curiosity as I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: You could always split the complex number into two, the real and complex part, so 2 columns and use a regular ML model, if this makes sense.

Comment: Never heard of any, it's hard to imagine an application of ML where that would make sense.

Comment: @user2974951 I get what you mean, but I'm more interested in how complex numbers could be useful at all, not in how it's implemented.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the positional encoding in the [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper, on which Bert and other popular modern models seem to be based, looks like a Fourier transform of the position to me. So you could probably say these popular models use complex numbers.

Comment: Fourier transform of a time series? [(I have a post on the imaginary components of Fourier transforms that some of you might be interested in reading.)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62491/fourier-transform-is-an-isomorphism-but-we-don-t-get-when-each-frequency-appea)

Comment: I think the given answer addresses the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out there are Neural Networks which are designed to work with complex numbers:

[A Survey of Complex-Valued Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.12249)

> Artificial neural networks (ANNs) based machine learning models and
> especially deep learning models have been widely applied in computer
> vision, signal processing, wireless communications, and many other
> domains, where complex numbers occur either naturally or by design.
> However, most of the current implementations of ANNs and machine
> learning frameworks are using real numbers rather than complex
> numbers. There are growing interests in building ANNs using complex
> numbers, and exploring the potential advantages of the so-called
> complex-valued neural networks (CVNNs) over their real-valued
> counterparts. In this paper, we discuss the recent development of
> CVNNs by performing a survey of the works on CVNNs in the literature.
> Specifically, a detailed review of various CVNNs in terms of
> activation function, learning and optimization, input and output
> representations, and their applications in tasks such as signal
> processing and computer vision are provided, followed by a discussion
> on some pertinent challenges and future research directions.

There are also complex-valued SVMs:

[Complex and Hypercomplex-Valued Support Vector Machines: A Survey](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334817859_Complex_and_Hypercomplex-Valued_Support_Vector_Machines_A_Survey)

> In recent years, the field of complex, hypercomplex-valued and
> geometric Support Vector Machines (SVM) has undergone immense progress
> due to the compatibility of complex and hypercomplex number
> representations with analytic signals, as well as the power of
> description that geometric entities provide to object descriptors.
> Thus, several interesting applications can be developed using these
> types of data and algorithms, such as signal processing, pattern
> recognition, classification of electromagnetic signals, light,
> sonic/ultrasonic and quantum waves, chaos in the complex domain, phase
> and phase-sensitive signal processing and nonlinear filtering,
> frequency, time-frequency and spatiotemporal domain processing,
> quantum computation, robotics, control, time series prediction, and
> visual servoing, among others. This paper presents and discusses the
> importance, recent progress, prospective applications, and future
> directions of complex, hypercomplex-valued and geometric Support
> Vector Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example for how researchers are playing with it as related to the descriptions above: [https://pratt.duke.edu/about/news/imaginary-numbers-machine-learning#:~:text=Using%20complex%20numbers%20in%20machine,more%20objects%20with%20more%20precision](https://pratt.duke.edu/about/news/imaginary-numbers-machine-learning#:%7E:text=Using%20complex%20numbers%20in%20machine,more%20objects%20with%20more%20precision).